# How to set docker labels on ECS agent container?

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, datadog

In a AWS ECS cluster each cluster instance runs the ecs-agent [1] as a docker container. Next to that container I run datadog-agent [2] also as a container. The datadog-agent monitors all other containers and ship their logs to DataDog. In order to have the log of each container tagged by name I've added a specific docker label [3] to each container with the respective name. However, I'm not been able to add a docker label to the ecs-agent itself.

Is there a way to add custom docker labels to the ecs-agent container?

[1] - https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent

[2] - https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-agent

[3] - https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_collection/docker/

Answer (score 0):

How are you spinning up ecs-agent container? What is docker run command?. Did you try like below?.

```
sudo docker run --name ecs-agent \
--detach=true \
--restart=on-failure:10 \
--volume=/var/run:/var/run \
--volume=/var/log/ecs/:/log \
--volume=/var/lib/ecs/data:/data \
--volume=/etc/ecs:/etc/ecs \
--net=host \
--env-file=/etc/ecs/ecs.config \
--label=myLabelName=amazon-ecs-agent \
amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest
```

Comment: The ecs-agent container is being spun up by a pre-installed service on the ECS optimised AMI. I'm looking for the place where such command is issued, or the configuration for it is defined.

Comment: Amazon ECS AMI is using https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-init library for starting ecs-agent docker container.
Based on their docker client code written, it looks like it's not supporting any label for ecs-agent.
https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-init/blob/master/ecs-init/docker/docker.go .
I would recommend a feature request on this github project or amazon-ecs-agent project should help you for your needs. It's a reasonable request though.